# Google Motion Chart - Cannot get data from query to display

Tags: apex, visualforce, charts

I have created an aggregate query for a custom object to get the data I need to the google motion chart.

I have tested the query and it returns the data I need. However, when I try to call it in the chart (VF page) I get a message that says "First and second columns must be entity and time."

The query is large so I have had to set the VF page to readonly. I thought that might be the issue but the I filtered the data to return only 120 rows and still get the same "error". I am thinking it must be something with the date format? Really, at this point I just don't know what to try next.

Here is the chart I am trying to adapt: https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#motion_chart

Any suggestions as to what I am missing?

Controller:

```
public class Groupfor3RE{
// Data class

    public class Data {
        public String entity { get; set; } 
        public String chan { get; set; }     
        public Integer tre { get; set; }
        public String tar { get; set; }        
        public Integer rr { get; set; }
        public Integer fte { get; set; }
        public String vert { get; set; }
        public String terr { get; set; }              
        public Integer rrr { get; set; }
        public String tier { get; set; }
        public Date time1 { get; set; }






        public Data(String entity,  String chan, Integer tre, String tar, Integer rr, Integer fte, 
                    String vert, String terr,  Integer rrr,  String tier, Date time1) {
            this.entity = entity;
            this.chan = chan;
            this.tre = tre;
            this.tar = tar;
            this.rr = rr;
            this.fte = fte;
            this.vert = vert;            
            this.terr = terr;            
            this.rrr = rrr;
            this.tier = tier;
            this.time1 = time1;


        }
    }
    public List<Data> getChartData1(){
    List<AggregateResult> arList = [SELECT  Account_Management_Type__c Type, 
                                    Sales_Channel__c Channel,
                                    AVG(X3RE__c) cThreeRE ,
                                    Target_Industry_from_account__c Target,
                                    AVG(Total_RR_Converted_to_USD__c)cRR, 
                                    MAX(FTE__c) cFTE,
                                    Territory_Vertical__c Vertical,
                                    Territory_from_account__c Territory, 
                                    AVG(Referenceable_Recurring_Revenue_R_RR__c) cRRR,  
                                    Tier__c Tier,
                                    Date__c Day

                                    from X3RE_Snapshot_Data__c

                                    group by  Account_Management_Type__c, Sales_Channel__c,  Target_Industry_from_account__c, 
                                    Territory_Vertical__c  , Territory_from_account__c ,  Tier__c, Date__c];

    List<Data> dataList = new List<Data>();
    for (AggregateResult ar : arList){       
        String Type = String.valueOf(ar.get('Type'));
        String Channel = String.valueOf(ar.get('Channel'));       
        Integer cThree_RE = Integer.valueOf(ar.get('cThreeRE'));        
        String Target = String.valueOf(ar.get('Target'));        
        Integer cRR = Integer.valueOf(ar.get('cRR')); 
        Integer cFTE = Integer.valueOf(ar.get('cFTE'));
        String Vertical = String.valueOf(ar.get('Vertical'));
        String Territory = String.valueOf(ar.get('Territory'));        
        Integer cRRR = Integer.valueOf(ar.get('cRRR'));   
        String Tier = String.valueOf(ar.get('Tier'));        
        Date Day = Date.valueOf(ar.get('Day'));


        dataList.add(new Data( Type, Channel, cThree_RE, Target, cRR, cFTE, Vertical,  
                               Territory,  cRRR,  Tier,  Day));
}



return dataList;

}


    }
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="Groupfor3RE" sidebar="false" showheader="false" readonly="true">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['motionchart']});

    function drawVisualization() {
var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Type', 'Date', '3RE'],
            <apex:repeat value="{!ChartData1}" var="c">
               ['{!c.entity}','{!c.time1}','{!c.tre}'],
           </apex:repeat>
        ]);
       var formatter_short = new google.visualization.DateFormat({formatType: 'short'});
     formatter_short.format(data, 1);    


       var motionchart = new google.visualization.MotionChart(
          document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      motionchart.draw(data, {'width': 800, 'height': 400});
    }


    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
  </script>

<body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
<div id="chart_div" ></div>
</body>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: did u get  your problem solved

Comment: I never did get it to work with a motion chart.

Answer (score 1):

Yes motion chart is showing correct error as your second column is of `String` type not a `Date`

You are iterating it as **'{!c.time1}'** So the final output will be string value of `date`.

Second column must be of Date type means:

```
 ['Apples', new Date(1988,0,1), 400]
```